# Android TCP client service -Not working

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-service, tcpclient

im making an app that connects via TCP with a java server in diferent activities, so as a read here the best practice is to use an android service.

this is the first socket code i write so i really dont know what im doing

i run the server in netbeans in pc and app in my phone, but it doesn't work, whats my mistake?

the ip adress is the private ip of my pc where the server runs, because im runnig the app in my phone

here is the server code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket=new ServerSocket(1001);

        while(true){
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: "+clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase()+"\n";
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
        }


    }
}
```

here is the code of my service

```
package com.remedialguns.smartourist;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ConnectionService extends Service{


    Socket s;
    PrintStream os;
    public static int serverPort=1001;
    public static String serverIP="192.168.1.104";
    Place[] PlacesToShow = new Place[10];

    private static final String TAG="com.remedialguns.smartourist";
    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return myBinder;
    }

    public void sendProfileData(String userId, String gender,int age, String Country, int[] preferences){
        //send profile data to server
    }

    public String test(){
        String test="test";
        String response="";
        try {
            InetAddress serverAdress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
            s=new Socket(serverAdress, serverPort);
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            outToClient.writeBytes(test);
            response = inFromClient.readLine();
            //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())));
            //out.println(test);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(response);
        return response;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        s=new Socket();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }





    public Place[] getPlaces(){
        //here a send a String to server and receive an object Place[]



        //F̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ Test data
        PlacesToShow[0]= new Place("MUSEO","Museo Nacional Agropecuario", 0.15, 0.4, 0.12);
        PlacesToShow[1]= new Place("MUSEO","Museo Arqueológico Junín",0.10, 0.78, 0.44);
        PlacesToShow[2]= new Place("MUSEO","Museo Botero", 0.2, 0.8, 0.08);
        PlacesToShow[3]= new Place("MUSEO","Museo de Zea", 0.3, 0.65, 0.23);
        PlacesToShow[4]= new Place("MUSEO","MUSEO DEL ORO", 0.13, 0.56, 0.12);
        PlacesToShow[5]= new Place("MUSEO","MUSEO DE ARTE COLONIAL", 0.3, 0.67, 0.14);
        PlacesToShow[6]= new Place("MUSEO","MUSEO HISTORICO DE LA POLICIA NACIONAL", 0.34, 0.3, 0.33);
        PlacesToShow[8]= new Place("MUSEO","MUSEO DE LOS NIÑOS", 0.05, 0.65, 0.03);
        PlacesToShow[7]= new Place("MUSEO","Museo Nacional", 0.15, 0.4, 0.12);
        PlacesToShow[9]= new Place("MUSEO","MUSEO MILITAR", 0.07, 0.5, 0.6);
        return PlacesToShow;
    }



    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        ConnectionService getService(){
            return ConnectionService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code where i call the test method.
the methos is called in onCreate method and the method called before that is working.

```
package com.remedialguns.smartourist;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import com.remedialguns.smartourist.ConnectionService.LocalBinder;

import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConnectionService tcpService;
    boolean isBound=false;
    //Place[] PlacesToShow=tcpService.getPlaces();
    Place[] PlacesToShow=new Place[10];



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class);
        bindService(i, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        if (isBound) {
            PlacesToShow = tcpService.getPlaces();
            tcpService.test();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private ServiceConnection myConnection=new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            tcpService = binder.getService();
            PlacesToShow = tcpService.getPlaces();
            ListAdapter MyAdapter = new MyAdapter(ListActivity.this, PlacesToShow);

            ListView ListPlaces = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyList);

            ListPlaces.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

            ListPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            Context context = view.getContext();
                            TextView textViewItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name));
                            String name = textViewItem.getText().toString();
                            TextView textViewItem2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
                            String descripcion = textViewItem2.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "lugar: " + name + ", descripcion: " + descripcion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            isBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            isBound=false;
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: This might help, skip to the client section: http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/

Comment: Did I miss the question?

Comment: server dosn't receive anything, and i dont know why.

Comment: You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator.